# Gauge with levels with colors and names Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Please help me to draw gauge like below image Thanks in Advance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlbNn.png)

Comment: Please provide a minimal working code example, or at least post any attempts that you've made. :)

Comment: Here is an example with some JS - https://codepen.io/jaketrent/pen/eloGk